# Cutting strings

Tags: javascript, string

I'm following the excersises in the book Eloquent Javascript and came up to this piece of code:

```
function between(string, start, end)
    {
        // Start AT the last character position of the start string

        var startAt = string.indexOf(start) + start.length;

        //Count the position of the end string first character
        var endAt = string.indexOf(end, startAt);

        return string.slice(startAt, endAt);

    }

    var betweenIn = between('Inazuma Eleven', 'Ina', 'ven');
    console.log(betweenIn);
```

Code works fine. It extracts a piece of string between in. Now I tried to really understand this piece, but one thing isn't clear to me. The variable endAt checks the string's first character position of the third given parameter, (in this case my string is 'Inazuma Eleven' end the parameter is 'ven'. I need that for slicing the string, BUT it seems that the second parameter of the indexOf method doesn't do anything. If I remove it, I get the same results. Why is this?

Comment: what do you mean by saying: `I get the same results`? above code should return `zuma Ele`

Comment: If I leave startAt from the endAt variable, I still get the same result. I wonder why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter of `indexOf` defaults to 0. This is the place in the string where it will start looking for your matching substring.

Starting after the end of the start string ensures that a) your end string doesn't match the first instance of it if the start string and end string are identical, and b) you have to scan less of the target string so the code runs faster.

In this instance, your start and end strings are different, so the outcome is the same. However since the `indexOf` method will be searching more of the string (starting from 0 instead of the 4th character) it will run fractionally slower.

Comment: Ah! You are saying that if I leave the startAt argument out, it has to look from the 0th position, and if I leave it in it'll start from the position given. So it all has to do with peformance?

Comment: @Marciano Not only, the a) is very important. Try `var betweenIn = between('Inazuma Eleven', 'a', 'a');`, you'll see what it does.